# Why does C++ CRTP template give invalid argument error?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class `Basis` which is templated on another class `DERIVED` via CRTP. This class has an inner class which operates as a functor and does the bulk of the work

```cpp
template <typename DERIVED>
class Basis {
  template <int M> // M is the degree of approximation
  class Functor {
    double operator()(Eigen::Matrix<double, M, 1> values) {
      // Use specific function in DERIVED
    ...
    }
  };
...
};
```

So a specific class like `Fourier` looks something like

```cpp
class Fourier : public Basis<Fourier> { // use CRTP
  ...
};
```

Now I wish to alias a third class `template <typename T> Worker` such as

```cpp
template <typename BASIS, int M>
using Approx = Worker<typename BASIS::Functor<M> >;
```

so I can use it like

```cpp
Approx<Fourier, 3>
```

but the aliasing gives me the error

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
   30 |     Worker< typename BASIS::Functor<M> >;
      |                                        ^
```

Does anybody have an idea what the issue might be? The error message doesn't give more details, and using

```cpp
template <int M>
using Approx = Worker<Fourier::Functor<M> >;
```

works fine.

I'm happy to give more details if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You also need `template`:

```
template <typename BASIS, int M>
using Approx = Worker<typename BASIS::template Functor<M> >;
//                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oh snap that worked. Is the explanation that since Functor is also a template type, the compiler needs to know this exclusively? Why can't it infer it directly?

Comment: Also, I'll accept this as the answer the moment SO allows me to.